# Powershell ISE says "Running script" upon opening, and never lets me run my script

Tags: powershell

On several servers just this week, when I open the Powershell ISE (as admin or otherwise) it just says "Running script / selection. Press Ctrl+Break to stop..." and the green Run Script and Run Selection icons are gray. However, I havent run any code yet. Ive let it sit there all day with no change. Ive tried hitting Ctrl+Break, the red STOP box grays out but it still says running. Ive tried Ctrl+x, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+Break.. all with the same result. I tried opening a Powershell window and the prompt never shows. I tried closing all the Powershell and ISE windows, logging off any other users, logging off myself and back in, checking ProcMon, Handle.exe. I cant see what is running. The only solution Ive found so far is rebooting the server. 
Plot twist: I also had an end user report this same issue on her Win10 desktop. 
I tried Google, but I just cant seem to get the right phrase to get any useful results for this issue. Sure rebooting "fixes" it, but I fear this will also be happening on the production servers and rebooting in the middle of the day is not an option. 
Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Having Powershell ISE open and then logging out is known to cause it to freeze. this is likely what happens to you. My only workaround is to close Powershell ISE when you are done, with it, and stay connected when you run a script.

Comment: If a script runs on startup of the ISE, then that normally means, it's in the user profile, or being called by the shortcut you are using. Open each user profile and remove code you don't want to happen. If this run still happens, I'd default to you've been compromised and your ISE has been messed with. Try just starring the console host to see if you get the same running message, if not then you've isolated the oddity to the ISE. Download the former ISE preview and see if you get the same thing.  ---https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise-preview/

Comment: I also tried the host console with the same result. I tried the host console, host console as administrator, ISE and ISE as administrator, all the same issue. Closing and re-opening the consoles also had no effect on the results. I also checked with ProcMon, and nothing Powersheel related remained open when closing the consoles.  I also shecked with the server team, they do not run any Powershell scripts on login, and no one modified the shortcuts or profile scripts, but I will take a look and see If there is anything in them.